# Grafana <> InfluxDB2 | Find the difference in query

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux, influxql

I am using k6 (using xk6-output-influxdb) to write test results to InfluxDB2. However, I can't understand why the InfluxQL (A) and Flux (B) query return different results.

PS - group by fill(0), fill(null), etc doesn't make a difference if that matters.

[image: Queries]

Comment: Wouldn't group by time affect this?

Comment: @markalex, there are no additional time filters under group by. The interval is the same for both queries and there was no other data inserted during that time (last 5 mins).